# amp-list src url not fetching data

Tags: twig, amp-list

I am using amp-list inside a twig file for creating a select dropdown. But the twig file is throwing an error *Unexpected character "#"* for the line  *{{#countries}}*. When this line is commented out the url fetches the data correctly. Please see the code below:-

```
<section class="card">
        <h2>Country</h2>
        <amp-list src="https://ampbyexample.com/json/cart.json" layout="fixed-height" height="80" >
            <template type="amp-mustache">
                <label for="country">Countries</label>
                <select id="country"
                        on="
      change:
        AMP.setState({
          countries: dropdown.items[0].countries.filter(x => x.profileTitle == event.value)[0]
        })">
                    <option value="">Choose a country</option>
                    {{#countries}}
                    <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
                    {{/countries}}
                </select>
            </template>
        </amp-list>
    </section>
```

Should I add something to the amp-list to tell it to wait till the data is fetched or is the {{#countries}} pattern not usable in twig? Really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to adjust the `twig lexer` in order to be able to use that `amp`-bundle

Comment: as @DarkBee stated, you are mixing both template delimiters.   https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee and @Christian Felix for your responses. Can i use both  the template delimiters at the same time? I created this function in my Controller  but it still did not save the problem.          `private function setTwigConfiguration()
    {
        $path = dirname(__DIR__, 5) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        require_once $path;

        $twig = new \Twig_Environment();
        $lexer = new \Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
            'tag_variable'  => array('{{#', '}}')
        ));
        $twig->setLexer($lexer);
    } `